# Create a thread with a stack at a specific address

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to control where the thread stacks will be created in VM?
I'm having VM fragmentation issues due to some thread stacks, and it would be very helpful if I could force them to load inside a given range (after 0x60000000 for example)

Comment: That's not possible.  The kernel is highly aware of the stack of a thread, necessary to deal correctly with this site's name.  And to setup the kernel mode shadow stack so a thread can make kernel calls.  The winapi doesn't provide a way to convince it to use your preferences.  VM fragmentation is a non-issue today, 32-bit operating systems were yesterday.